# How can I submit value to javascript without submitting onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I submit an input value to a javascript function without submitting my onclick button? Here is the code:

```
 <input id="demo" type="text" value="1">
```

I want to be able to submit the value to a javascript here is the code:

```
 function myFunction() {

 var x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
```

Basically i want to submit my input value without having my submit button. Here is the code:

```
 <input id="demo" type="text">

 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
```

How can I submit my input without having a submit button?

Comment: ummm AJAX? it has been covered *soooooo* many times on SO. Did you search?

Comment: @Jakub he doesn't wants Ajax, he wants page to be submited but with the button hidden.

Comment: What does "submit my input" mean? Are you actually asking for a `<form>`?

Comment: Bascially submit the input as onclick without pressing submit so if the value by id is present then the function should automatically work.

Comment: Look at [change event MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is really simple>

```
    <form action="url.php">
<input type="text" value="some value" name="name_input" />
    </form>
```

Only you can press ENTER in "name_input" field for send the form data

Answer (score 1):

You can call `myFunction()`, when `demo` loses the focus

```
$('#demo').blur(myFunction);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7q8f3/)

and/or when the user presses <kbd>return</kbd>

```
$('#demo').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        myFunction();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7q8f3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do this is using jquery

```
function myfunction()
{
    var val = document.getElementById("demo").value;

    $.post( "test.php", { value: val})
     .done(function( data ) {
      alert( "Value submited");
    });
 }
```

Call myfunction() on blur event. like this

```
<input id="demo" type="text" value="1" onblue="myfunction()">
```

This will send your value to test.php page and you can do the rest. If you want to avoid jquery then do it with simple AJAX with javascript directly.